# Path length maxiumum for DirPickerCtrl under Unix

Tags: python, unix, wxpython

I am using wxpython 3.0.2.0, Python 2.7.13, and I work with FreeBSD, so I have a Unix-system.

My Questions is about the wx.DirPickerCtrl

```
dir_picker_style = wx.DIRP_DIR_MUST_EXIST | wx.DIRP_USE_TEXTCTRL
dir_picker = wx.DirPickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, path=path, message="test",
                              style=dir_picker_style)
```

If my path is more than 32 characters (including backslashes) then for

```
value = dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value
```

value was an empty string (u'') and I have to set it manually with

```
dir_picker.GetChildren()[0].SetValue(dir_picker.Path)
```

and everything works fine. But my co-workers use Windows and for them a path with more than 32 characters works fine as well.

Does someone know this bug? And does someone know why it happens?

Thanks for your time!

---

Here is an runnable example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(250,250))
        dir_picker_style = wx.DIRP_DIR_MUST_EXIST | wx.DIRP_USE_TEXTCTRL

        path1 = "more/than/"
        path2 = "more/than/thirtytwo/characters/more"

        dir_picker = wx.DirPickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                      path=path1,
                                      style=dir_picker_style,
                                      pos=(100,50))

        statictext1 = wx.StaticText(self, label =
                                          "dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value: ",
                                          pos=(100,90))
        control1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_READONLY, pos=(100,130))
        control1.SetValue(dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value)
        control1.Enable(False)

        statictext2 = wx.StaticText(self, 
                                    label = "dir_picker.GetPath(): ",
                                    pos=(100,170))
        control2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_READONLY|wx.GROW,
                               pos=(100,200))
        control2.SetValue(dir_picker.GetPath())
        control2.Enable(False)

        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'DirPicker')
app.MainLoop()
```

When I use path1 it will be shown in every textctrl, but when I use path2 it is only shown in the last one. (But when I double click on the window path2 also appears in the first textctrl. For me this is a really strange behavor).

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your issue using wxPython 3.0.2.0 Classic, Python 2.7 and Xubuntu 16.04. When I try accessing `TextCtrl.Value`, I get an `AttributeError`.

I tried using the documented API instead, which is calling `GetPath()`, and it works fine with long folder names:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.picker = wx.DirPickerCtrl(self)
        self.picker.Bind(wx.EVT_DIRPICKER_CHANGED, self.onPicked)

    def onPicked(self, event):
        print self.picker.GetPath()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Pickers')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

I tried it again and I don't get an AttributeError but
1.
value = dir_path.GetPath(), works fine even with long folder names
2.
value = dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value, returns an empty string (u'')
3. 
value = dir_picker.GetChildren()[0].GetValue(), returns an empty string too.

Comment: I think `dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value` is just the wrong way to go about it. The API is clearly stated to be `GetPath` in the documentation.

Interestingly, if I add the `wx.DIRP_USE_TEXTCTRL` to my example above, the `self.picker.TextCtrl.Value` works fine for long folder names.

Comment: Thanks for your time. In my GUI there is a textctrl with no entry if the path is more than 32 characters so that's the reason I used `dir_picker.TextCtrl.Value` to see what's in my textctrl. This is the reason of my question: the textctrl is empty but `dir_path.GetPath()` does have the right value: how can this happen?

Comment: I think you'll have to post a small, runnable example that I can try as I can't replicate the issue

Comment: I just added a runnable example. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are just setting your TextCtrl, `control1`, to the initial value of the DirPickerCtrl. It won't update when you choose a different directory unless you handing an event. You have no events bound, so nothing will happen.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just added the 2. and 3. TextCtrl to see if there is a difference and it is! When I use path1 (less than 32 characters) it is written in the textctrl of the dir_picker, when I use path2 (more than 32 characters) it is not (unless I click on the window)